# getting the error: Query input must contain at least one table or query

Tags: c#, oledb

i get this error :Query input must contain at least one table or query
my code is:

```
    using (OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=timetabledata.accdb")){                       
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                           string q = "INSERT INTO timehourly (teacherid,subjectid) Values ('@teacherID','@subjid')" + " WHERE hour='@i' AND dayid='@ds'";
                          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacherID", Convert.ToInt32(teacher_combo.SelectedValue).ToString());
                           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subjid",  Convert.ToInt32(subject_combo.SelectedValue).ToString());
                           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i",i.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ds",ds.Tables[0].Rows[k].ItemArray[0].ToString());
                            cmd.CommandText = q;
        cmd.Connection = myCon;
        myCon.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("successfully added", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);}
```

Comment: First thing to fix: use parameterized SQL instead of string concatenation. It'll make your SQL easier to read, avoid conversion issues, and avoid SQL injection attacks. Fix that, then see whether your problem still occurs. If it does, edit your better code into the question, fix the formatting (the indentation was all over the place in the initial post) and you're more likely to get help. Oh, and describe your schema.

Comment: i do but no thing changes..ho to resolve

Comment: Well you haven't edited your question to show the new code...

Comment: Could you edit it again so it's more readable? As I mentioned in my first comment, your original post had horrible indentation, and this is just as bad. Use the preview to see how your post is going to look to everyone, and put the effort in so that it looks how *you'd* like it to look if you were the one trying to help.

Comment: d'acc.. je veux essayer

Comment: @Ghadir I have edited my answer with additional information.  Please review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the apostrophes from your parameter declarations.  Also verify that there is data in the values you are passing to the query.  Also assign your `CommandText` before adding the parameters.

Also you can wrap the `OleDbCommand` in a `using` statement also as it implementes `IDisposable`.

Then, you are trying to do an `INSERT` with a `WHERE` clause, which will not work.

`INSERT` statements are meant to actually "insert" a row into the table, you cannot insert a row where there is already a row.

What you are looking for is `UPDATE` - I have edited the syntax below to reflect this.

```
using (OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=timetabledata.accdb"))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{                       
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    string q = "UPDATE timehourly SET teacheridh = @teacherId, SET subjectidh = @subjid  WHERE hour=@i AND dayid=@ds";
    cmd.CommandText = q;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacherID", Convert.ToInt32(teacher_combo.SelectedValue).ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subjid",  Convert.ToInt32(subject_combo.SelectedValue).ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i",i.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ds",ds.Tables[0].Rows[k].ItemArray[0].ToString());

    cmd.Connection = myCon;
    myCon.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("successfully added", "Caption",        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

If you really did mean to do an `INSERT` then just take the `WHERE` out of your `q` string.

Comment: @Ghadir Now I see it.  You can't do an INSERT with WHERE.  Are you trying to UPDATE the table?  Or Insert a new row?

Comment: @Ghadir great!  Please mark my answer as the answer by hitting the green checkmark below the vote arrows =)