# vb.net Inserting data to access database

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I have the following code to input data into my Access database, but I am getting the following error.

```
Query input must contain at least one table or query.
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is the section of code that they is mentioning the lines.

```
Private Sub EditAddButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EditAddButton.Click

    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\*******************;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=************;")
    Dim insertsql As String
    Try
        insertsql = "INSERT INTO RepairOrders" & _
        "(ROOtherInfo, ROJobType, ROJobTime, RODelPicDate, RONo)" & _
        "VALUES (@other, @type, @time, @delpic, @jobno) WHERE ROJobNo = @jobno"

        Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(insertsql, conn)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@other", AddOtherText.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", AddTypeCombo.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", AddTimeCombo.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@delpic", AddDatePick.Value.Date.ToString)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobno", AddJobText.Text)

        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Booking Added!")
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

I have replaced certain information with asterixs' to cover some sensitive information.

## EDIT:

Now I am getting a syntax error :(

```
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\*********************************;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=***********;")
    Dim insertsql As String
    Try
        insertsql = "UPDATE RepairOrders SET ROOther = @other, SET RONo = @jobno, SET ROJobType = @type, SET ROJobTime = @time, SET RODelPicDate = @delpic WHERE RONo = @jobno"

        Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(insertsql, conn)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@other", AddOtherText.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", AddTypeCombo.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", AddTimeCombo.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@delpic", AddDatePick.Value.Date.ToString)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobno", AddJobText.Text)

        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Booking Added!")
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437458/getting-the-error-query-input-must-contain-at-least-one-table-or-query

duplication, insert statement must not contain WHERE clause. if you want to use where use it on UPDATE

Comment: Here you should use `update` instead of `insert`

Comment: I edited my code, it's in the edit section in my OP. I am now getting a syntax error? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have too many SET statements, and OleDb requires '?' for parameters, and you must take care about the amount of them, and the order they are specified. This is a bit cleaned up, take a look at [OLEDB Parameterized Query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12048152/16391) for a more thorough example.

```
Try
        insertsql = "UPDATE RepairOrders 
                       SET ROOther = ?
                        , RONo = ?
                        ,  ROJobType = ?
                        , SET ROJobTime = ?
                        , SET RODelPicDate = ?
                     WHERE RONo = ?"
    Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(insertsql, conn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", AddOtherText.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", AddJobText.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", AddTypeCombo.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", AddTimeCombo.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", AddDatePick.Value.Date.ToString)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", AddJobText.Text)

    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Booking Added!")
    conn.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```