# C# to access INSERT INTO query with condtions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, insert

I am trying to enter some data into a database I have in access but only in certain rows (due to conditions youll see in the code) however it throws back the error: 'Query input must contain at least one table or query.' but I am unsure what I need to do to fix this.

The code I have is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++)
{
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(CONNECTION STRING HERE);

    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

    connection.Open();
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TotalPlayerName ([Team], [Complete]) VALUES ('1', true) WHERE Team = '' AND Complete = false AND Rating = " + team1List[i];
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.Connection = connection;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Here is the design view for the database:
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to insert new data, or update existing data?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437458/getting-the-error-query-input-must-contain-at-least-one-table-or-query

You appear to be trying to do an UPDATE and using an INSERT to accomplish it.

Comment: why don't you wrap the `command.ExecutNonQuery()` around a `try{}catch{} and see if it's throwing an error.. also what is the primary key on your table.. is it `Team` try inserting a number like `99` just to see.. I bet this is an issue with trying to insert duplicate keys also convert your Insert statement to utilize `Parameters`

Comment: @Khale_Kitha how do you come to that conclusion when the their is clearly an `INSERT` command in the `CommandText` ?

Comment: Because he's trying to use INSERT WHERE, which gives that error.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha are you saying that he can't do an INSERT with a Where clause..? I hope that's not the case..

Comment: @Alby are you familiar with using the syntax for Insert statement when working with Access to use the `?,?,?` Parameters..? I would refactor your query to work for starters using Parameterized query as well as wrapping the Database objects around a `using` I will post an example on how to use Parameters when working with MS Access and it should be easy to follow.

Comment: @MethodMan Not without a WHERE NOT EXISTS or with the WHERE being part of a SELECT that he's using for the INSERT, no.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I think I understand what you were talking about earlier .. sorry for the confusion..

Comment: I think using an update query would be better for me, also the design view for my database is now on my original question

Comment: @Alby could you also provide some sample rows of the table?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to update some rows not to insert, so the statement has to look like

```
 command.CommandText = "update TotalPlayerName set Team = '1', Complete = true WHERE Team = '' AND Complete = false AND Rating = " + team1List[i]
```

EDIT: corrected a SQL syntax problem

Comment: Thank you, this has stopped the error but it does not update the Complete column to true, any idea why?

Comment: @Alby How is your table designed in access? Could you please post an image of your table (with all field defintions)

Comment: @Alby i've corrected my SQL know it should work for you.

Comment: what if the value in Team is NULL I think that the OP should tell us what the dataschema for that field is .. does it allow nulls or not and what the default value is when a new record is inserted..

Comment: For some reason this code doesnt throw any errors but doesnt update the database.

Comment: @Alby see my first comment, we could not help you if you don't give us more information

Comment: I'll edit my question with a screenshot of the database layout.